# Javascript Download remote picture in background

Tags: javascript, ajax

In my project, I need to implement an Image viewer to display pictures stored on the server on an HTML Page (thumbnail first and on click on the thumbnail display the full screen picture).

Currently, the server is providing me an URL (ex: https://testsrv/getImage?id=0) which is sending back the picture to the browser (Servlet sending a File to an OutputStream). For the moment, I'm just adding an a href hyperlink to download the picture that's ok.
but If I want to improve this, I would need to download the pictures (thumbnail and full size picture) in background while opening the html page to show the thumbnail on the screen.

I assume I would need to download the picture by using AJAX in background and store the pictures in a local temporary folder but if you have some examples to provide me that would be very helpful...

EDIT1:
I finally found a way thanks to the comments based on the onload service:

```
            var image = document.images[0];
        var downloadingImage = new Image();
        downloadingImage.onload = function(){
            image.src = this.src;   
            document.getElementById("img_ref").setAttribute('href', "../../../testSRV/GetPhoto?id="+id_attach);
            console.log('preloaded');
        };
        downloadingImage.src = "../../../testSRV/GetPhoto?id="+id_attach;
```

Comment: Have a look at the preload attribute of link nodes. Depending on what exactly will happen with the pics, just adding those preload links for all images may suffice, since it'll already fetch the pics and keep them cached until the web page needs to render them.

Comment: The basic image preloader used for ages: `var img = document.createElement("img"); img.onload = function () { console.log('preloaded'}; img.src="http://example.com/image.gif";`